# Set Handlebar class on the fly

Tags: ember.js, handlebars.js

I'd like to update the class of a `div` according to the user input. A simple input text that need to be validated.
I have to go with a helper but I can't figure it out.

```
<div class="{{validationClass}}">   
    <p>{{input type="text" id="titleInput" value=title placeholder="Title"}}</p>
</div>
```

When there's nothing written in the text field I'd like to surround the box with the red colour, after the used typed a single character I want it to go default.
So, according to bootstrap 2.x I'd need to set the div class to `control-group error` or `control-group success` etc.

I've never created a helper so I'm struggling, I don't know how to call it and how to return the desired string to be replaced in `{{validationClass}}`

Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use the [bind-attr](http://emberjs.com/guides/templates/binding-element-class-names/) helper .

This is a sample:

```
<script type="text/x-handlebars" data-template-name="index">
  <div {{bind-attr class=":control-group validationClass"}}>   
    <p>{{input type="text" id="titleInput" value=title placeholder="Title"}}</p>
  </div>
</script>

App.IndexController = Ember.ObjectController.extend({
    title: null,
    validationClass: function() {
        var title = this.get('title');
        return title ? 'success' :  'error';
    }.property('title')
});
```

http://jsfiddle.net/marciojunior/6Kgty/

Answer (score 1):

Use `{{bind-attr}}` helper

```
{{!hbs}}
 <div {{bind-attr class=":control-group isError:error"}}>
  {{input type="text" class="form-control" value=testVal}}
 </div>

//Controller
App.ApplicationController = Em.Controller.extend({
  testVal: '',
  isError: Em.computed.empty('testVal')
});
```

Sameple [Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/selvaG/EXyr2/3/)

Comment: thanks! my handlebar is something like `<script type="text/x-handlebars" id="post/_edit">` do you know what the naming convention would be? for the Control I mean.